# $\lVert u +v \rVert =\lVert u \rVert +\lVert v\rVert$ only when $u$ and $v$ have the same direction

Tags: linear-algebra

> How can I prove that $\lVert u +v \rVert =\lVert u \rVert +\lVert v\rVert$ only when $u$ and $v$ have the same direction?

I started by raising the two parts of the equation to the second power, but I got stuck at $u \cdot v = \lVert u \rVert \, \lVert v \rVert$.

Comment: What is $uv$ defined as, to you?

Comment: The scalar product of the vectors u and v

Comment: I know what you call it. I am asking how it's defined. Without that, there is no hope to compare $uv$ and $\|u\|\|v\|$.

Comment: @Arthur, are you asking for norms different from the Euclidean one?

Comment: @mvw No. I'm trying to tell him that without definitions you can't prove anything, and the details of the proof will depend on the details of the definitions. For that matter, the definition of $\|u\|$ could be necessary as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fact that $u \cdot v = \|u\| \|v\| \cos \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u$ and $v$. You can show that $$\|u+v\|^2  = \left( \|u\| + \|v\| \right)^2$$ if and only if $\cos \theta = 1$, that is, if and only if $\theta = 0^\circ$.

If this condition holds then a quick calculation verifies $u = \alpha v$ for $\alpha = \frac{u \cdot v}{v \cdot v} > 0$ because in this case $\|u - \alpha v\|^2 = 0$.

Comment: Sorry to dig this back up...but I was working on essentially the same problem in Spivak's "Calculus". The fact that equality holds for $180^{\circ}$ means that the vectors can be pointing in opposite directions, right? I only ask because Spivak's solution manual states "$\mathbf{u}=a\mathbf{v}$" for some number $a \gt 0$, suggesting that only $ \theta = 0^{\circ} $ is possible (because otherwise, $a \lt 0$ should be valid as well)

Comment: I'm not sure what I meant. It may have been a response to an earlier edit of the question, but my "if and only if" isn't true. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\lVert u +v \rVert =\lVert u \rVert +\lVert v\rVert \iff \lVert u +v \rVert^2=\|u\|^2+2\|u\|\|v\|+\|v\|^2$$

and

$$\|u+v\|^2=(u+v)\cdot (u+v)=\|u\|^2+2u\cdot v+\|v\|^2$$

then recall that

$$u\cdot v=\|u\|\|v\| \cos \theta$$

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to show that for a euclidean vector space $(V,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ and $u,v\in V$:

$$||u+v||=||u||+||v||\text{ iff }u\text{ and }v\text{ are linearly dependent}$$

i.e. $||u+v||=||u||+||v||$ iff $u=\lambda v$.

---

To show this, you may assume that $u,v\neq\mathbf0$ as otherwise the statement is immediate.

---

From right to left, suppose that $u=\lambda v$, then

$$||u+v||=||\lambda v+v||=(1+\lambda)||v||=||v||+\lambda||v||=||v||+||\lambda v||=||v||+||u||$$

---

From left to right, suppose $||u+v||=||u||+||v||$, i.e. $||u+v||^2=(||u||+||v||)^2$. Now,

$$||u+v||^2=\langle u+v,u+v\rangle=\langle u,u\rangle+\langle u,v\rangle+\langle v,u\rangle+\langle v,v\rangle\leq ||v||^2+2|\langle v,u\rangle|+||u||^2$$

and

$$(||u||+||v||)^2=||v||^2+2||v||\cdot||u||+||u||^2$$

i.e.

$$||v||^2+2||v||\cdot||u||+||u||^2\leq ||v||^2+2|\langle v,u\rangle|+||u||^2$$

and thus $||v||\cdot||u||\leq |\langle v,u\rangle|$ and by Cauchy-Schwarz, i.e. $|\langle v,u\rangle|\leq ||v||\cdot||u||$, we have

$$||v||\cdot ||u||=||\langle v,u\rangle||$$

Thus, $u=\lambda v$.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comments earlier, start with $(u+v)^2$:
\begin{align}
(u + v)^2 &= u^2 + 2 u\cdot v + v^2  \iff \\
\lVert u + v \rVert^2 &= \lVert u \rVert^2 + \lVert v \rVert^2 + 
2 \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert \cos \angle(u, v) \\
&= (\lVert u \rVert + \lVert v \rVert)^2 +
2 \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert (\cos \angle(u, v) - 1) \iff \\
\lVert u + v \rVert&=
\sqrt{(\lVert u \rVert + \lVert v \rVert)^2 + 2 \lVert u \rVert \lVert v \rVert (\cos \angle(u, v) - 1)} 
\end{align}
where I assumed $\cdot$ to be the standard scalar product and $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ to be the Euclidean $\lVert \cdot \rVert_2$ norm.

The claimed result holds if 
$$
\cos \angle(u, v) - 1 = 0
$$
which is true if $u$ and $v$ have angle $0$ between them, i.e. show in the same direction.